# How can I change my code to make the items stay visible after been scrolled over once?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

How can I change my code to make the items stay visible after they have been scrolled over once? I am a really beginner at coding, so any help and tips are welcome. Thank you for your help in advance!

```css
.inline-photo {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(60px) ;
  transition: transform 3000ms 500ms cubic-bezier(0,1,.3,1),
              opacity 300ms 500ms ease-out;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}

.inline-photo.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
}
```

```
var scroll = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
            function(callback){ window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60)};

            var elementsToShow = document.querySelectorAll('.show-on-scroll');

            function loop() {

  elementsToShow.forEach(function (element) {
    if (isElementInViewport(element)) {
      element.classList.add('is-visible');
    } else {
      element.classList.remove('is-visible');
    }
  });

  scroll(loop);
}

loop();

function isElementInViewport(el) {

  if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
    el = el[0];
  }
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    (rect.top <= 0
      && rect.bottom >= 0)
    ||
    (rect.bottom >= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight))
    ||
    (rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight))
  );
}
```

My end goal is to get the stay visible after they have appeared once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate logic from appliance within your CSS.

Create a class that applies the visibility.

```
.inline-photo.is-shown {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
}
```

And let `is-visible` manage the state in your code.

```
if (isElementInViewport(element)) {
  element.classList.add('is-visible', 'is-shown');
} else {
  element.classList.remove('is-visible');
}
```